# Grails: <script> vs. <g:javascript>

Tags: javascript, grails

Can anyone please explain the difference between these two tags and how Grails sees one vs. the other? I have a table with click and hover effects which don't seem to happen when I import jquery using:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

but do when I do this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and I want to use the previous tag because other Grails tags such and remote forms rely on it for their built in ajax capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the custom Grails tag and tries to load the Javascript library by that name.  If you're using the Resources plugin, then the call [delegates](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Tags/javascript.html) to that for loading of the library.  Take a look at JavascriptTagLib.groovy to see what the custom tag does.

The latter is just the regular HTML script element, and attempts to fetch a script at the location provided.

The issue you're running into may slightly depend on the version of Grails you are running too.  Looks like 'jQuery' is [not a valid library](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Tags/javascript.html) in Grails 1.3.x:

> library (optional) - The name of the library to include. Either "prototype", "scriptaculous", "yahoo" or "dojo"

You may want to make sure that your path is correct and you either have the [Grails jQuery plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery) installed, or you have the library in your `web-app/js` directory.  Grails 2.x comes with jQuery by default, but older versions did not.

Comment: I am using Grails 2.3.8.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman Are other `r:require` or Resource tags working as expected?  You might be missing a call to `r:layoutResources`